# video can not be played from South Africa node which upload video is fine

Tags: azure

Our development team is using the media service to upload the video files on node in South Africa, that is in order to transcoding into adaptive streaming with using AES encryption of video assets.
We found the videos can be played and uploaded on our side, and the URL is unavailable. We can not obtain the callback under we sent request to this domain. However, we can not ping this domain successfully.
We don't know what happened in it or which step is wrong we made.

Our test URL:
http://sasaimedia-sano1.streaming.media.azure.net/b3ebc3ad-4132-4904-a20d-b3dab6d27d2c/2BD344E96A12668D55BA38ABFE12747D.ism/manifest

I also try to use VPN, but it did not work

Comment: What is the error message? I clicked on the link and was able to download the manifest file.

Comment: This problem has been solved,this link can not be resolved becausse of the Operation and maintenance personnel not open the Streaming Endpoint,make the the Streaming Endpoint int the Running state ,it's all rignt.Thank you for answering my question